# My bitcoin address and name

Tags: transactions

Please how will the receiver of the bitcoin know that I send the bitcoin into his wallet. And how do i send the bitcoin into another person's wallet

Answer (score 1):

Typically the receiver will create a different address for every payment he expects.

That way, once the expected amount of coins have arrived at the expected address, the receiver knows which payment was fullfilled.

This is a better approach than trying to figure out who paid - something that's not generally possible and hurts Bitcoin's privacy. Typically you don't care who pays a bill, only which bill was paid.

Answer (score 0):

That's two questions, but I'll attempt to answer both:

The "receiver" of a bitcoin transaction is really just an address that in your case happens to be a peson and where that address is associated with a Wallet, e.g. a software app, installed on a SmartPhone.

The wallet app will have an area within it allowing users to view transactions. Depending on the wallet, it will either display as coins sent and received, or provide a link to an external service such as https://blockchain.info where info about the transaction can be viewed. Using the latter, the receiver (actually, anyone) can see that the address you used to send coins to, has been used as an "Output" in a transaction, and the address used to send the coins (e.g. your own wallet address) has been used as an "Input" to that transaction.

In summary: If both the sender and receiver address are displayed on blockchain.info, and have at least 6 "Confirmations", you can pretty much safely assume that the coins have been successfully sent and received.

As for how to send coins to another wallet, you'd follow the same principle:

1). Obtain address from the person you wish to pay
2). Using any wallet, punch in that address
3). Select the amount of coin to send to that address
4). Hit "send" or "pay" or whatever.

I hope that helps.

Comment: If you're happy with the answers, please consider marking it as "accepted".